# Minimum hitting set for set of all subsets of size $m$ in $[n]$?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Let $M$ be the set of all subsets of size $k$ in $[n]$. Is there a known formula for the smallest hitting set of $M$? Where a hitting set is a set $H$ such that $H \cap S \neq \emptyset$, $\forall S \in M$. On a few small examples I've done it seems that the smallest hitting set always has size $n-k+1$, but I can't prove this holds in general, any thoughts? I know this can also be presented in terms of a vertex cover on a k-uniform hypergraph.

Comment: Yes, it is $n-k+1$. Think about it a bit harder; why is it impossible for a set of size $k$ to have empty intersection with a set of size $n-k+1$, if both are subsets of $n$? Conversely, why is true that when $H$ is size at most $n-k$, there exists a subset $S$ of size $k$ where $H \cap S$ is empty?

Comment: If there is a set of size $n-k-1$, then there are only $k-1$ elements of $[n]$ missing from this set, so there can't exist any subset of size $k$ in $[n]$ that has empty intersection with this set. Conversely, if a set has size $n-k$, then there are exactly $k$ elements of $[n]$ missing from this set, so let these $k$ elements be a set and the intersection the two sets is empty. Thus, the smallest hitting set of $M$ has size $n-k+1$. Does that sound right?

Comment: That's right! (after changing that first $n-k-1$ to $n-(k-1))$.